# Which SStables files are in compaction state?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to monitor/predict the filesystem usage during and after any kind of compaction by watching the `nodetool compactionstats` command output on a Cassandra **1.2** cluster.

At the moment, I know the list of SStables files and their percentage of tombstones.

What I'm missing, and can't find a way to discover, is which file are being compacted per compaction task. I can be one (the minimum threshold) or more...

Example:

```
pending tasks: 1
compaction type  keyspace  column family   completed      total          unit     progress
Compaction       XXXX      YYYY            451926443876   745412896390   bytes    60.63%
```

How can I match each line to one or multiple SSTables files?

I tried with the bytes count, but I can't find a sum of files byte count that match the total column. Also, I don't think this approach is viable due to the long file list.

I might also be using a wrong approach to achieve my goal.

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: grep Compacting /var/log/cassandra/system.log seems to do the job.